# Targeting css for interior page elements

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and I want to change the css on an element if the user is on the index.php page or single.php

The element css

```
#nav-icon span {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

on the index page I want it to remain #fff, but on single.php I want it to be #000.

EDIT - One issue is that the #nav-icon div is in the header.php (so it is on every page)

Comment: Please take other parent of `#nav-icon` to override `background-color:#000`.

Comment: Add a class to the `<body>` tag representing the page you're on. CSS does not have access to URL information. Eg, in `single.php` ~ `<body class="single">`. Then you can use `.single #nav-icon span`

Comment: put the style inside the single page. background-color: #000 !important; when you in single page site this background read and if not the background-color: #fff is read. or you can create in the javascript.. make a IF ELSE if single.php == currentURL then override the background-color

Comment: I think the below link might be helpful for you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125315/style-something-only-on-the-home-page

Comment: Made an edit to the question which I overlooked the importance of, and may change the situation a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution using jQuery

If you are in index page

```
$(document).find('#nav-icon span').css({
  'background-color': '#fff'
});
```

In single.php

```
$(document).find('#nav-icon span').css({
  'background-color': '#000'
});
```

Hope this will help you.